# How do you uninstall APK and PIP from Docker Image?

Tags: pip, alpine-linux

I'm working on some "common sense" hardening of one of my docker containers and my line of thinking suggests that I could attempt to uninstall APK and PIP from the Alpine linux image after I finish installing all of my dependencies.

I'm having a hard time finding any information on doing so. My line of thinking is that the container is ephemeral so there would never be a need to install anything to a running container.

Comment: IMHO it makes sense to remove `pip` for example as you wont install anything in production unless there is a need for that and it should be in a few cases. however I would leave `apk` there so i can install pip if i have to.. Also running the container as non root would prevent a non root user to use apk itself

Comment: any suggestion on the removal of pip itself? I've not been successful.

Comment: Could you explain what already have you tried and what kind of issues you have faced ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to remove `pip` by uninstalling the `py-pip` package:

`apk del py-pip`

Followed by deleting pip's cache:

`# rm -rf /<HOME_DIR>/.cache/pip`

Then, for removing `apk`, delete the `apk` binary and folders:

```
# rm -f /sbin/apk
# rm -rf /etc/apk
# rm -rf /lib/apk
# rm -rf /usr/share/apk
# rm -rf /var/lib/apk
```

I haven't done Docker hardening/jailing myself, but removing the package manager seems like a common practice for reducing the possible attack surface. Here's an interesting post taking a similar approach:

- [Minimising your attack surface by building highly specialised docker images - example for .NET Core 2.1 applications](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/minimising-your-attack-surface-by-building-highly-specialised-docker-images-example-for-net-b7bb177ab647)

Comment: Great info, thanks. When I run the apk del py-pip it returns no error, but if I attempt a pip command afterwards it still works. So far the only thing I've been able to do is rm the pip from /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 9):

For removing `apk`, this will also work and ensure proper removal: `apk --purge del apk-tools`